# Existence of Continuous Surjective map from $[0, \pi] \cup [2\pi ,3\pi]$ to $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is the following statement true/false ?

There exists a continuous map from $[0,\pi] \cup [2\pi ,3\pi]$ onto $[0,1]$

I think the statement is true.

My strategy to construct such a function was to map the points of $[0, \pi]$ to a single point (say $0$  for an instance) and then construct the map for $[2\pi, 3\pi]$ to $[0,1]$

But, I am not sure whether this is process correct or not ?

Can someone tell me whether my approach is correct or not ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the second set of the domain: $[\pi,2\pi]$ or $[2\pi,3\pi]$?

Comment: @bjorn93:Sorry, it was a typo. I have corrected  it.

Comment: What stops you from taking $x\mapsto\sin x$?

Comment: What if you map the first interval to $[0,1/2]$ and the second to $[1/2,1]$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop: Very clever solution, Thank you.

Comment: @sat091 Your idea can also work. Of course, it depends on how exactly you map $[2\pi,3\pi]$ to $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. You may also define functions such as $$f(x)=\frac { x}{ \pi} , x\in [0,\pi]$$ and $$f(x) =\frac { x}{\pi}  -2 , x\in [2\pi, 3\pi]$$